# Display image after image, as in layers to create a single image

Tags: android, image, layer, layerdrawable

Hi I am making a hangman, and I need to show image after image each time the player fails an attempt eg head first, then the body ect. I'm doing a layerdrawable but not how to scale it to the original image, how climb as I show the image and the images layer by layer to create the hangman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think the simplest way would be to decide what size your image is going to be.  Then just use several PNG images with one body-part drawn on them and a clear background.  As long as the images are all exactly over one another, you should see the familiar image of a stick figure drawn one part at a time.

Hope this helps.